# Azure file share credentials for Docker

Tags: azure, docker

I'm trying to use File Share to mount a volume in a docker container.

I'm trying to get the following variables, as mention in the official documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files

--azure-file-volume-account-name mldatafileshare \
--azure-file-volume-account-key  XXXXXX \
--azure-file-volume-share-name datamlfileshare \

I'm the deploying the container with the following CLI code:

```
/home/luis/bin/az container create \
    --resource-group mlcontainers2 \
    --name automl3 \
    --image mlcontainers2.azurecr.io/samples/modeldiagnostics \
    --registry-login-server mlcontainers2.azurecr.io \
    --registry-password EeFxSRT2ghUNzlD2ny=iuGwVHEqy4aFZ   \
    --registry-username mlcontainers2 \
    --ports 80 5000 5100 \
    --azure-file-volume-account-name mldatafileshare \
    --azure-file-volume-account-key  XXXXXX \
    --azure-file-volume-share-name datamlfileshare \
    --azure-file-volume-mount-path /app/data_automl \
    --memory 3 \
    --ip-address public
```

It's created sucessfully, with when I make a call to the API 
(the container is running a flask app) I get this error:

```
2019-09-18 19:39:20 wk-caas-42de550704fc4996be1b9660860edcd1-39ad43ac741df9f9f1c698 werkzeug[8] INFO 10.240.255.56 - - [18/Sep/2019 19:39:20] "POST /api/AutoML HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

I have tried without mounting the volume and I get the exact same error, hence I think the issue is that the container is not accessing the File Share unit.

I'm taking the values for the unit "--azure-file-volume-account-name, --azure-file-volume-account-key  and  --azure-file-volume-share-name "
from the following places:

azure-file-volume-account-name: **mldatafileshare**

[image]

azure-file-volume-share-name: **XXXX** 
I'm taking that one from the same page:

[image]

And last one, azure-file-volume-share-name: **datamlfileshare**:

[image]

Is the file I created inside the account, mldatafileshare.

EDIT:

Also, when I try to access the account on the browser I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the message that you provided, I must explain something to you. First, you cannot access the Azure File Share through the browser just via its URL when the Azure File Share is managed by Azure.

Second, when you use the storage account name and the storage account key to mount the file share to the Azure container instance volume as the persistent storage, you can access the file share with the admin permission.

Here is the example, you can follow the steps in [Mount an Azure file share in Azure Container Instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-volume-azure-files). After the mount is finished, you can see the file share like below:

[image]

Comment: That screenshot is from a container or a VM?

Comment: File share is working for me on a VM but failing on the containers

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez It's from the Azure File Share which mounts to the container instance.

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez If it works for you please accept it as the answer.